# split() method on string not working

Tags: java, string, split

i want to split a string which contains +, i m using split() on String object as:
but it shows exception.

```
class StringTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String val= "004+0345564";
        String arr[]=val.split("+");
        for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
class StringTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String val= "004+0345564";
        String arr[]=val.split("\\+");
        for(int i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`String.split` takes a *regular expression* as its argument. A `+` in a regular expression has a special meaning. (One or more of previous).

If you want a literal `+`, you need to *escape* it using `\\+`. (The regular expression grammar is `\+` but you need to escape the backslash itself in Java using a second backslash).

Answer (score 3):

```
String arr[] = val.split("\\+");
```

instead of

```
String arr[]=val.split("+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Split takes regex. You need to escape `+`

```
String arr[]=val.split("\\+")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String arr[] = val.split("\\+");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
    String arr[] = val.split("\\+");
```

Instead of

```
    String arr[]=val.split("+");
```

The split method takes regex as inputs. You can also refer [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to confirm the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actual syntax is

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)

//or

public String[] split(String regex)
```

So use, below one.

```
String arr[] = val.split("\\+",0);
```